# what is the best way to secure queries from a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I heard that mysql query variables or queries are being depreciated and it's not advisable to use them any more, well I'm trying to update my simple website and I want to add some security features for my forms and my database, I have this query below

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET first_name='$name', last_name='$name2', username='$username' , phone_number='$phone', email='$email', user_level='$user_level', type='$type' WHERE id='$id'")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

What's the best way I can write a query without being attacked?

Comment: If you really want security, move away from `mysql_*` functions ..

Comment: "mysql queries" are NOT being deprecated. the `mysql_*()` functions ARE deprecated.

Comment: Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql. mysql functions are deprecated.

Comment: @Thrustmaster: Security is not about using MySQLi or PDO, but about using parameterized queries: it's very easy to write unsafe code with both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/995926). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).